# existence of Markov operators not generated by transition probability function

Tags: probability-distributions

Transition probability functions can always be used to generate Markov operators, correct? So is it correct to say that a Markov process is a collection of Markov operators? On the other hand, are there Markov operators NOT generated by transition probability functions?

Comment: Markov operators on what space?

Comment: L-1 space of a Borel measure space.